# How to use wirefilter over an infinite stream of data

Tags: rust, rust-crates

I am writing a program to use [wirefilter](http://github.com/cloudflare/wirefilter/) in order to filter data from an infinite stream.

But it seems that I cannot use a compiled ast in a loop because of lifetimes   and when I try to compile, this is the output:

```
error: borrowed data cannot be stored outside of its closure
  --> src/main.rs:34:33
   |
31 |     let filter = ast.compile();
   |         ------ ...so that variable is valid at time of its declaration
32 | 
33 |     for my_struct in data.filter(|my_struct| {
   |                                  ----------- borrowed data cannot outlive this closure
34 |         let execution_context = my_struct.execution_context();
   |                                 ^^^^^^^^^ ----------------- cannot infer an appropriate lifetime...
   |                                 |
   |                                 cannot be stored outside of its closure

error: aborting due to previous error

error: Could not compile `wirefilter_playground`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

main.rs

```rust
use wirefilter::{ExecutionContext, Scheme};

lazy_static::lazy_static! {
    static ref SCHEME: Scheme = Scheme! {
        port: Int
    };
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyStruct {
    port: i32,
}

impl MyStruct {
    fn scheme() -> &'static Scheme {
        &SCHEME
    }

    fn execution_context(&self) -> ExecutionContext {
        let mut ctx = ExecutionContext::new(Self::scheme());
        ctx.set_field_value("port", self.port).unwrap();

        ctx
    }
}

fn main() -> Result<(), failure::Error> {
    let data = expensive_data_iterator();
    let scheme = MyStruct::scheme();
    let ast = scheme.parse("port in {2 5}")?;
    let filter = ast.compile();

    for my_struct in data.filter(|my_struct| {
        let execution_context = my_struct.execution_context();
        filter.execute(&execution_context).unwrap()
    }).take(10) {
        println!("{:?}", my_struct);
    }

    Ok(())
}

fn expensive_data_iterator() -> impl Iterator<Item=MyStruct> {
    (0..).map(|port| MyStruct { port })
}
```

Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "wirefilter_playground"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
wirefilter-engine = "0.6.1"
failure = "0.1.5"
lazy_static = "1.3.0"
```

is it possible to make it work? I would like to yield only the filtered data for the final user otherwise the amount of data would be huge in memory.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: And if you create a `move` closure? `data.filter(move |my_struct| { /*...*/ }`

Comment: Hey there @FrenchBoiethios the same error would happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem is with the lifetime elision in return structs. In particular this code:

```
fn execution_context(&self) -> ExecutionContext {
    //...
}
```

is equivalent to this one:

```
fn execution_context<'s>(&'s self) -> ExecutionContext<'s> {
    //...
}
```

Which becomes obvious once you realize that `ExecutionContext` has an associated lifetime.

The lifetime of `ExecutionContext` does not have to match that of the `MyStruct` so you probably want to write:

```
fn execution_context<'e>(&self) -> ExecutionContext<'e> {
    //...
}
```

or maybe:

```
fn execution_context<'s, 'e>(&'s self) -> ExecutionContext<'e>
where 'e: 's {
    //...
}
```

depending on whether your context will eventually refer to any content of `MyStruct`.

Comment: Hi Rodrigo, thank you!
In my mind, the elision was going to infer 'e and not 's.